# How to make a quiz in android?

Tags: java, android

For my final year application I need to make a quiz or a trivia game. Basically, all I need to do is a questionnaire with 26 questions that have images and multiple answers. I found a site but now I realize that doesn't allow multiple answers. Actually it's really cool because at the end it shows the correct answers and I know how to integrate it in my application. My question is - do you know a good site for making questions for Android or at least do you ever found a link to a related project?

I know, this is not really a good questions and probably will be closed, but I'm really close to finishing my application and this is the only thing that is missing. Thanks!

Comment: try searching on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look into [github open source repositories](https://github.com/search?q=trivia%20game%20android&ref=commandbar) or ["quiz" repositories](https://github.com/search?q=android%20quiz&ref=commandbar) for the information you want.

Comment: this is not a answer. you are suggesting a link can be posted as a comment.

Comment: I agree it's not the best answer- but the question was simply asking for a good site for information. I think, in part, it was the bad quality of the question.