# I am going to develop a new Quiz application in Android. When I click on the wrong option it has to show red color how can we do that?

Tags: android

I am new to this Quiz Applications.

I am using radio buttons here. When I click on wrong options it will come on red color and it has to display correct answer also. Now here is my code. When i click on the next button it will appear like this. Thanks in advance.
here total, correct and wrong are static variables to display the final score in another class.

```
            RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            String ansText = uans.getText().toString();

            if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[flag])) {


                correct++;
            } else {



                wrong++;
            }
            flag++;

            if (flag < question.length) {
                tv.setText(question[flag]);
                rb1.setText(options[flag * 3]);
                rb2.setText(options[flag * 3 + 1]);
                rb3.setText(options[flag * 3 + 2]);
                marks = correct - wrong;

            } else {
                marks = correct - wrong;
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ResultActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);

            }
            if (flag == question.length) {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ResultActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
                Level1Activity.this.finish();
            }
            total = question.length;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a quiz in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643362/how-to-make-a-quiz-in-android)

Comment: There is a wealth of information on SO already about android quiz apps, try searching the site first to find a way to make your question more specific.

Answer (score 2):

add these statement where you find a wrong ans, that is in else part, where you need to set a red color.

if your color.xml is like:

```
<color name="errorColor">#f00</color>
```

then

```
uans.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

and also set the ans with another color